# Fugas de memoria en Android

Tags: java, android, app, manejo-de-memoria

Buenas, mi primera vez por aca. Estoy aprendiendo de forma totalmente autodidacta a programar en *Java*, principalmente para *Android*.

---

Me vendría muy bien la opinión de los que saben sobre las fugas de memoria (Por ahora es lo que se me está haciendo más difícil comprender.)

La pregunta en definitiva es, ¿Qué parte de estos códigos provoca **fugas de memoria**?

---

Esto es lo que muestra el *DDMS* después de un cambio de orientación de pantalla filtrando por el nombre del paquete principal: [DDMS Output](https://gist.github.com/viejocadillac/258a47fd906ce02f079dd67b48d99ae8) ... y los códigos de la clases involucradas, son:

***ScreenSearchFragment.java***

```
public class ScreenSearchFragment extends Fragment{

    private RecyclerSearchAdapter myAdapter;
    private DialogSearch dialog;
    private static final String TAG_DIALOG = "Search Dialog";

    @NonNull
    public static ScreenSearchFragment newInstance(String tabTitle){
        String title = "title";

        ScreenSearchFragment fragment = new ScreenSearchFragment();
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putString(title, tabTitle);
        fragment.setArguments(arguments);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_screen_definition, container, false);
        FloatingActionButton btnAddWord = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_add_word);
        if(dialog == null) {
            Log.d("ScreenSearchFragment", "dialog es null");
            dialog = new DialogSearch();
        }

        btnAddWord.setOnClickListener(new MyOnClickListener(dialog, getFragmentManager()));

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        initAdapter();
        setRecycler(view);

    }

    private void initAdapter(){
        List<Word> words = new ArrayList<>();
        myAdapter = new RecyclerSearchAdapter(words);

        //Examples
        myAdapter.addWord(new Word("Word 1", "Here is the definition of the word"));
        myAdapter.addWord(new Word("Word 2", "Here is the definition of the word"));
        myAdapter.addWord(new Word("Word 3", "Here is the definition of the word"));
        myAdapter.addWord(new Word("Word 4", "Here is the definition of the word"));
        myAdapter.addWord(new Word("Word 5", "Here is the definition of the word"));

        //Example multiline
        myAdapter.addWord(new Word("Word 6", "Here \nis \nthe \ndefinition \nof \nthe \nword"));
    }

    private void setRecycler(View view){
        RecyclerView rV = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_search);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(view.getContext());

        rV.setLayoutManager(llm);
        rV.setAdapter(myAdapter);

        DefaultItemAnimator itmAnim = new DefaultItemAnimator();

        itmAnim.setAddDuration(1000);
        itmAnim.setRemoveDuration(200);
        itmAnim.setMoveDuration(800);

        rV.setItemAnimator(itmAnim);

        //Delete item when is swiped to LEFT
        ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleCallback = new MySimpleCallback();

        ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(simpleCallback);
        itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(rV);
    }

    private static class MyOnClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
        private final DialogSearch dialog;
        private final FragmentManager fragmentManager;

        MyOnClickListener(DialogSearch dialog, FragmentManager fm) {
            this.dialog = dialog;
            this.fragmentManager = fm;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(v.getId() == R.id.btn_add_word) {
                if (!dialog.isVisible()) {
                    dialog.show(fragmentManager, TAG_DIALOG);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private class MySimpleCallback extends ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback {
        MySimpleCallback() {
            super(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder,
                              RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
            if (direction == ItemTouchHelper.LEFT){
                myAdapter.removeWord(viewHolder.getLayoutPosition());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

***DialogSearch.java***

```
public class DialogSearch extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private Button btnCancel;
    private Button btnSearch;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog, container, false);
        btnSearch = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_search);
        btnCancel = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progress_search);

        TextInputLayout inputLayout = (TextInputLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.search_input_layout);

        TextInputEditText etWord = (TextInputEditText) view.findViewById(R.id.et_word);

        etWord.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(inputLayout, btnSearch));

        btnSearch.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnCancel.setOnClickListener(this);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void dismiss() {
        if(! (progressBar.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)){
            super.dismiss();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
        if(! (progressBar.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)){
            setCancelable(true);
            super.onCancel(dialog);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.btn_search:
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btnCancel.setEnabled(true);
                btnSearch.setEnabled(false);
                setCancelable(false);
                //Download definition in a new AsyncTask
                break;

            case R.id.btn_cancel:
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                //Stop the AsyncTask if is running
                dismiss();
                break;
        }
    }

    private static class MyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher{
        private TextInputLayout inputLayout;
        private Button button;

        MyTextWatcher(TextInputLayout inputLayout, Button button){
            this.inputLayout = inputLayout;
            this.button = button;
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            if(button.getId() == R.id.btn_search){
                if(editable.length() < 3){
                    button.setEnabled(false);
                    inputLayout.setError("Invalid Text.");
                    if(editable.length() == 0){
                        inputLayout.setError(null);
                    }
                }else{
                    button.setEnabled(true);
                    button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    inputLayout.setError(null);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

***MainActivity.java***

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    private MainFragmentAdapter fragmentAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initFragmentAdapter();
        initViews();
    }

    private void initFragmentAdapter(){
        fragmentAdapter = new MainFragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        //Add fragments here
        fragmentAdapter.addFragment(ScreenAntonimosFragment.newInstance("Example 1"));
        fragmentAdapter.addFragment(ScreenSinonimosFragment.newInstance("Example 2"));

        fragmentAdapter.addFragment(ScreenSearchFragment.newInstance("Search"));
    }

    private void initViews(){

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.main_view_pager);
        if(viewPager != null){
            viewPager.setAdapter(fragmentAdapter);
        }

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_tab);
        if(tabLayout != null){
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        }

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        boolean opc = false;

        if(id == R.id.action_settings){
            opc = super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
        return opc;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tienes un problema de  "fugas de memoria" o solo quieres saber en este código donde podría provocarse.

Comment: La verdad que no se si los tengo ( Nunca me salio un OOM, pero lo que veo en el DDMS me resulta sospechoso ). Por eso es que me gustaría saber si en el código que he puesto es posible/encuentran alguna linea que sea propicia a producirlos. Gracias. @Elenasys